# trying to not to iterate on undefined or not available objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add type of material objects to the array using below code but getting an error when one of the object is not available.

and the error is

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): (intermediate value)(intermediate
> value)(intermediate value) is not iterable

```
        constructionSetMasterObject = cloneDeep(data);
        if (!constructionSetMasterObject.glazingOrGasMaterials.length) {
          console.log(constructionSetMasterObject);
          constructionSetMasterObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [
            ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials,  // here i am getting an error 
            ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials,
            ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingComplexMaterials
          ];
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.glazingGasMaterials;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.glazingSimpleMaterials;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.glazingComplexMaterials;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.gasMaterialId;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.simpleMaterialId;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.complexMaterialId;
          delete constructionSetMasterObject.opaqueMaterialId;
        }
```

and i tried the below one but it is not going to work out

```
...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials ||{}
```

the object `...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials` is not available and could any one please suggest any efficient way to check that if object is exist only iterate that or any other ways to avoid this situation.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `[...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials || []]` or `[...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials ?? []]`

Comment: some times this object is also not available `...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials,` and i do not want to add empty if that object is not defined

Comment: What do you mean by "not available"?

Comment: that object(`glazingSimpleMaterials`) is not there in `constructionSetMasterObject` array

Comment: Default them all. `constructionSetMasterObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials ?? [], ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials ?? [],            ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingComplexMaterials ?? []]` will handle any `undefined` or otherwise falsy `*Materials` arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that

```
 [...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials || {}]
```

Raises that error is because the default value you specified is an object `{}` which is not iterable.

Instead, the default value specified should be an iterable value, i.e. an empty array (`[]`).

```
constructionSetMasterObject.glazingOrGasMaterials = [
    ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingGasMaterials ?? [], 
    ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingSimpleMaterials ?? [], 
    ...constructionSetMasterObject?.glazingComplexMaterials ?? []
];
```

Note that I've chosen use the `??` operator above for consistency and symmetry with your existing use of `?.` but `||` would also work just fine.